# Flutter and Android Studio Publishing

Tags: android, flutter, publishing

Ok I am starting to get into the Flutter programming. I am in the process of implementing Flutter in Android Studio.

My question is when publishing a Kotlin app you have to publish with a .aab file for uploading to Google Play.

My question is that when I get to the publishing aspect of Flutter. Is the publishing straight forward, or do I need to convert anything to the .aab file to upload to the Play Store?

Will Android Studio convert everything needed for it to be .aab file?

Comment: Yes android studio will do everything for you. Just open the android project in android studio to publish the build, follow the usual steps of creating build and let android studio do his job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the Android module of your Flutter app in Android Studio and then generate a signed bundle like for a native Android app.

1. Tools -> Flutter -> Open for Editing in Android Studio
2. Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK ...

The [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android) also describe how to do this manually via command line.

Comment: I appreciate the help.. I am a WPF/Universal and Java/Kotlin developer. I have recently gotten into mobile development and I have been hearing Flutter is good for cross platform so I figure I would give it a try. I have apps on Google Play that are Kotlin. I am just new to flutter and learning the flutter language

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend reading the deployment document
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

also before publishing you need a generate a signing key, and use that key to sign the app.

also don't forget to change version In pubspec.yaml file

and you can read it more on the link or just youtube "Flutter deployment "

Comment: I appreciate it. I am a learning Flutter but I have several apps on Google Play that were built in Kotlin. So I am figuring out flutter and learning the language